# How do I stop my query from pulling duplicates?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Yes, I know this seems simple:

`SELECT DISTINCT(...)`

Except, it apparently isn't

Here is my actual Query:

```
SELECT 
    DeclinationReasons.Reason, 
    EmployeeInformation.ID, 
    EmployeeInformation.Employee, 
    EmployeeInformation.Active, 
    CompletedTrainings.DecShotDate, 
    CompletedTrainings.DecShotLocation, 
    CompletedTrainings.DecReason, 
    CompletedTrainings.DecExplanation, 
    IIf([DecShotLocation]="MCS","Yes","No") AS YesMCS, 
    IIf([DecReason]=1,1,0) AS YesAllergy, 
    IIf([DecReason]=2,1,0) AS YesImmune, 
    IIf([DecReason]=3,1,0) AS YesAdverse, 
    IIf([DecReason]=4,1,0) AS YesMedical, 
    IIf([DecReason]=5,1,0) AS YesSpiritual, 
    IIf([DecReason]=6,1,0) AS YesOther, 
    IIf([DecReason]=7,1,0) AS YesAlready
FROM 
    EmployeeInformation 
INNER JOIN (CompletedTrainings 
    LEFT JOIN DeclinationReasons ON CompletedTrainings.DecReason = DeclinationReasons.ReasonID) 
        ON EmployeeInformation.ID = CompletedTrainings.Employee
GROUP BY 
    DeclinationReasons.Reason, 
    EmployeeInformation.ID, 
    EmployeeInformation.Employee, 
    EmployeeInformation.Active, 
    CompletedTrainings.DecShotDate, 
    CompletedTrainings.DecShotLocation, 
    CompletedTrainings.DecReason, 
    CompletedTrainings.DecExplanation, 
    IIf([DecShotLocation]="MCS","Yes","No"), 
    IIf([DecReason]=1,1,0), 
    IIf([DecReason]=2,1,0), 
    IIf([DecReason]=3,1,0), 
    IIf([DecReason]=4,1,0), 
    IIf([DecReason]=5,1,0), 
    IIf([DecReason]=6,1,0), 
    IIf([DecReason]=7,1,0)
HAVING 
    ((((EmployeeInformation.Active) Like -1) 
        AND ((CompletedTrainings.DecShotDate + 365 >= DATE()) 
            OR (CompletedTrainings.DecShotDate IS NULL))));
```

This is Joining a few tables (obviously) in order to get a number of records. The problem is that if someone is duplicated on the table with a NULL in one of the date fields, and a date in another field, it pulls both the NULL and the DATE, or pulls multiple NULLS it might pull multiple dates but those are not present right at the moment.

I need the Nulls, they are actual data in this particular case, but if someone has a date and a NULL I need to pull only the newest record, I thought I could add MAX(RecordID) from the table, but that didn't change the results of the query either.

That code:

```
SELECT
    DeclinationReasons.Reason, 
    EmployeeInformation.ID, 
    EmployeeInformation.Employee, 
    EmployeeInformation.Active, 
    MAX(CompletedTrainings.RecordID), 
    CompletedTrainings.DecShotDate
    ...
```

And it returned the same issue, Duplicated EmployeeInformation.ID with different DecShotDate values.

Currently it returns:

| ID | Active | DecShotDate | etc. x a bunch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | date date | whatever goes |
| 2 | -1 |  | in these |
| 2 | -1 | date date | columns |

These are being used in a report, that is to determine the total number of employees who fit the criteria of the report. The NULLs in DecShotDate are needed as they show people who did not refuse to get a flu vaccine in the current year, while the dates are people who did refuse.

Now I have come up with one simple solution, I could add a column to the CompletedTrainings Table that contains a date or other value, and add that to the HAVING statement. This might be the right solution as this is a yearly training questionnaire that employees have to fill out. But I am asking for advice before doing this.

Am I right in thinking I need to add a column to filter by so that older data isn't being pulled, or should I be able to do this by pulling recordID, and did I just bork that part of the query up?

Edited to add raw table views:

EmployeeInformation Table:

| ID | Last | First | empID | Active | Termdate | DoH | Title | PT/FT/PD | PI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doe | Jane | 982 | -1 |  | date | Sr | PD | X |
| 2 | Roe | John | 278 | 0 | date | date | Jr | PD | X |
| 3 | Moe | Larry | 1232 | -1 |  | date | Sr | FT | X |
| 4 | Zoe | Debbie | 1424 | -1 |  | date | Sr | PT | X |

DeclinationReasons Table:

| ReasonID | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Allergy |
| 2 | Already got it |
| 3 | Illness |

CompletedTrainings Table:

| RecordID | Employee | Training | ... | DecShotdate | DecShotLocation | DecShotReason | DecExp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |  | date | location | 2 | text |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 3 | 4 |  | date | location | 3 | text |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |  | date | location | 1 | text |
| 6 | 4 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Wouldn't `MAX(DecShotDate)` solve your problem? If not, try to create a sub select grouped by whaterver you need, ordered by `DecShotDate DESC, RecordID DESC` (or maybe RecordID only) and take `FIRST(RecordID)`. Now use this RecordID to filter in the outer select, etiher with `WHERE RecordID in (sub select)` or by joining on the sub-select.

Comment: Tried that as well, and, while I would have thought it would, it didn't I get the same issue with a NULL date and a date being pulled.

Comment: Okay, better idea: in a sub- select determine the number of non-zero dates per group. Now, in the outer select, use this number to select `WHERE (sub select) = 0 OR DecShotdate IS NOT NULL`. So if there is no non-null date, allow null dates, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

After some serious soul searching, I decided to use another column and filter by that.

In the end my query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
(
SELECT RecordID, DecShotDate, DecShotLocation, DecReason, DecExplanation, Employee, 
IIf([DecShotLocation]="MCS","Yes","No") AS YesMCS, IIf([DecReason]=1,1,0) AS YesAllergy, 
IIf([DecReason]=2,1,0) AS YesImmune, IIf([DecReason]=3,1,0) AS YesAdverse, 
IIf([DecReason]=4,1,0) AS YesMedical, IIf([DecReason]=5,1,0) AS YesSpiritual, 
IIf([DecReason]=6,1,0) AS YesOther, IIf([DecReason]=7,1,0) AS YesAlready 
FROM CompletedTrainings WHERE (CompletedDate > DATE() - 365 ) AND (Training = 69))  AS T1 
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT ID, Active FROM EmployeeInformation)  AS T2 ON T1.Employee = T2.ID) 
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT Reason, ReasonID FROM DeclinationReasons)  AS T3 ON T1.DecReason = T3.ReasonID;
```

This may not have been the best solution, but it did exactly what I needed. Which is to get the information by latest entry into the database.

Previously I had tried to use MAX(), DISTINCT(), etc. but always had a problem of multiple records being retrieved. In this case, I intentionally SELECT the most recent records first, then join them to the results of the next query, and so on. Until I have all the required data for my report.

I write this in hopes someone else finds it useful. Or even better if someone tells me why this is wrong, so as to improve my own skills.